# StructureMap Scoping Nested Containers Per Task

Tags: structuremap

I have the need to create a nested StructureMap container per `Task`. How does StrucureMap track nested containers? Is it safe to have a nested container per `Task`, or should I attempt to instantiate all required services outside the `Task` and then inject the service instance? I will be using the `async` / `await` features of `C#` inside each `Task` and I want to ensure that the specific containers will always resolve back to the same instance and not be shared across `Task` boundaries.

Comment: I need the same. Have you got do this?